# Is it normal for the left pin on the Nikon SB-910’s 3-pin external power source terminal to be deeply recessed?

Tags: nikon, battery, hotshoe-flash, power

I’m examining the external power source terminal of my newly purchased Nikon SB-910 speedlight.

(The terminal is for connecting an external battery pack. It is located on the front side of the speedlight below the AF-assist red plastic cover. The terminal is under a small black Nikon-branded cover.)

The terminal has three pins, but the left pin is really short and is recessed deep into the socket. Is that normal? Does your SB-910 also have a recessed left pin?

I have watched several unboxing videos and read some reviews of the SB-910, but none of them show the power terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is normal, and a correct description.  The recessed pin is for safety, to keep out unapproved connections.  Be aware that there is about 325 volts on this cable.  It does not just attach a battery as such, but attaches a battery powered high voltage converter, which directly charges the flash capacitor.